# Common Punctuation Error?

Tags: punctuation

I saw a lot - I mean really a lot - of people putting a comma between verbs or verb phrases in their writings e.g.

> The house was colored in brown when it was built by my father in 1920,
>   and had a tall Zelkova tree in its front yard.

even native speakers often make same mistakes. As far as I know, if I want to keep the comma sentence should be as follows:

> The house was colored in brown when it was built by my father in 1920,
>   and it had a big Zelkova tree in its front yard.

Or should take out the comma.

Am I missing something or wrong? there are so many people making same punctuation errors that I feel I am wrong. I checked the Purdue OWL, and I am pretty sure it says such comma usage is wrong.

(Ref)
https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/owlprint/607/
Comma abuse > #13

Comment: Despite what the Purdue OWL says, the first clause in that sentence is long and complicated enough that I think the comma is justifiable.

Comment: First off, the Purdue OWL is not entirely trustworthy. Not everyone agrees with it. Second (as is said repeatedly here), punctuation is often a matter of style. If you want to be prescriptive and say *you must punctuate this way* then feel to do so. Better style guides than Purdue OWL exist, but I wouldn't take everything that even they say as written in concrete.

Comment: http://writingcenter.unc.edu/tips-and-tools/commas/
also says "MYTH: Long sentences need a comma. A really long sentence may be perfectly correct without commas. The length of a sentence does not determine whether you need a comma."

Comment: Oh, it is prescriptive vs descriptive stuff again. That makes sense then.

Comment: Found a related post, 
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87736/comma-a-punctuation-error?rq=1
Guess it was a matter of taste

Comment: Why do you think this is somehow a mistake?  Also, what does being a native speaker have to do with writing? That's different. And as for prescriptive/descriptive, that applies to language not to writing. There is no descriptive grammar of one's penmanship.

Comment: I was taught that such punctuation is unnecessary, and somehow I took it as such usage is a mistake. Now that I am glad that I don't have to be bothered by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sentence were:

> The house was colored in brown when my father built it in 1920 and had a red front door.

you really ***need*** a comma, because without the comma, it looks like the verb *had* belongs to *father* and not *house.* So the Purdue OWL's advice shouldn't really apply to sentences with subclauses.